# Can't remove python3.9 and change between other versions

Tags: python-3.x

I've installed python3.9 from the source code. Extracted the archive and did `sudo make install`. After that, I figured that since I didn't do `sudo make altinstall` the default version of Python became 3.9. Now when I type `python3 -V` it gives me Python3.9.0 and I can't change it back to 3.7 from update-alternatives screen. This is what I get:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.7   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.6   1         manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/python3.7   2         manual mode
```

It seems like Python3.9 doesn't have bin files in the `/usr/bin/python*`, so I can't uninstall it.
Can someone please help with the following:

1)Uninstalling Python3.9

2)Setting Python3.7 back as the default

P.S. Before I had installed python3.9, I only had those python versions in the list above, however I couldn't switch between 3.6 and 3.7. Every time I choose 3.7 as default, python version didn't change to 3.7 when I tried `python3 -V` What could be the problem behind this? I think should remove and install python3.7 again?

Comment: bash: type: -v: invalid option
type: usage: type [-afptP] name [name ...]
@MarkPlotnick

Comment: Sorry, what is the output of the command `type -a python3`

Comment: python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
@MarkPlotnick

Comment: I checked both directories and python3.9 is in /usr/local/bin/, but it's not in /usr/bin/. Is that why I can't display python3.9 when listing ```sudo update-alternatives --config python3``` ?@MarkPlotnick

Comment: OK, if you do `echo $PATH`, you probably have `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`. So no matter what `update-alternatives` does to the `/usr/bin/python3` link, your shell won't even consider running it. You can probably do `sudo mv /usr/local/bin/python3  /usr/local/bin/python3.bak` to make things work the way they used to, until you find a way to uninstall the local version of python.